# c# List of varying type set as object

Tags: c#, abstract-class, generic-list

I've created a generic search parameter class for reuse in several libraries (see below). I'm trying to find a better way to implement the list of values for each parameter. I will be passing a list of the parameters to a method but varying types for the values for each parameter. I've implemented it as simply type object and will convert to the correct type as necessary in my code, but I feel like there is probably a better way to do this and I'm not coming up with much. Anyone done anything similar or have a suggestion? Thanks!

### Generic Abstract Class:

```
public class SearchParameter<T>
{
    public T Name { get; set; }
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

### Inheriting Class:

```
public enum OrderSearchParameterNames
{
    Barcode,
    DateCompleted,
    DatePlaced,
    OrderStatus,
    UserId
}

public class OrderSearchParameter : SearchParameter<OrderSearchParameterNames>
{
    public OrderSearchParameter(OrderSearchParameterNames name, List<object> values)
    {
        Name = name;
        Values = values;
    }
}
```

### Example of method using the inherited class:

```
public ApiResponse<OrderWellplate, ApiResponseStatus> SearchOrders(int currentPageIndex, int pageSize, List<OrderSearchParameter> searchParameters, OrderSortParameter sortParameter, out int recordCount)
```

Comment: After playing with this a bunch and taking @theB suggestion, I believe I may end up going another route which will work better and will be simpler. I'm going to create a class that has the parameters I want to use for searching as properties. This will also allow me to control whether they can specify single/multiple values as well as the exact type necessary for the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of the list is the same as the type of `Name`

```
public class SearchParameter<T>
{
    public T Name { get; set; }
    public List<T> Values { get; set; }
    public SearchParameter(T name, List<T> values)
    {
        Name = name;
        Values = values;
    }
}
```

If the type of the list is different from the type of `Name`

```
public class SearchParameter<TName, TValues>
{
    public TName Name { get; set; }
    public List<TValues> { get; set; }

    public SearchParameter(TName name, List<TValues> values)
    {
        Name = name;
        Values = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The type of the list is different from the type of the name, but the types of the values in each list can be different from they type of values in another list. The second solution works for creating each individual search parameter and I have done something very similar, but once I've initialized all those search parameters I will need them in a List that I can pass to a method.

For example, I would build up several search parameters:

    SearchParameter DateCompleted = new SearchParameter<DateCompleted, DateTime>() { DateTime.UtcNow };

Comment: `SearchParameter DateCompleted = new SearchParameter<DateCompleted, DateTime>() { DateTime.UtcNow };

SearchParameter OrderStatus= new SearchParameter<OrderStatus, string>() { "In Progress" };
    
SearchParameter UserId= new SearchParameter<UserId, int>() { 1 };`